# Adding multiple nominal / recurring product to cart

Tags: magento

I am working with Magento 1.9  "Nominal product".

My requirement is to add multiple nominal products in to the cart.

When I try to add more than one nominal product it is showing an error message:
 --"Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote." –

I cant even add simple product with nominal product.

Is there any way to add more than one nominal product to cart in Magento?

Comment: Could you please add more details here ? For example what code are you using, what is the stack trace etc.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I am using Magento Normal flow I am not using any custom code to add product to cart.This is the error-----"<div id="message_ajax">Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote.</div>"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: ANd then: never give more info in comments. Always update your question instead!

Comment: "Always update your question instead!" thank you for your suggestion.Now can you please help in in the real problem.